# React-bootstrap cards not wrapping

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-bootstrap

My Code is:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styles from "./Cards.module.css";
import { CardDeck, Card } from "react-bootstrap";

const Cards = ({ animeArray }) => {
  const [aanimeArray, setAnimeArray] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setAnimeArray(animeArray);
  }, [animeArray]);

  if (!aanimeArray) {
    return;
  }
  console.log("Anime Array", aanimeArray);
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      {aanimeArray === [] ? (
        <h1>Search</h1>
      ) : (
        <CardDeck>
          {aanimeArray.map((anime) => {
            return (
              <Card>
                <Card.Img variant = "top"  src={anime.image_url} />
                <Card.Body>
                  <Card.Title>{anime.title}</Card.Title>
                </Card.Body>
                <Card.Footer>
                  <small className="text-muted">{anime.rated}</small>
                </Card.Footer>
              </Card>
            );
          })}
        </CardDeck>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cards;
```

I am not using any custom styling whatsoever.
The result of the above mentioned code is as seen on this image:
[Image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxeCL.png)

Comment: any input on my answer? please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the effort of making them wrap. In fact, as seen on the [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/cards/), majority of the developers' examples includes the CSS property `width` with a value of `18rem`.

Here is an example by leveraging `minWidth`:

```
const sampleStyle = {
  minWidth: "20%",
  flexGrow: 0
};

<Card style={sampleStyle}>
```

[image: Edit peaceful-smoke-v4gnc]

Answer (score 0):

First thing.

```
aanimeArray === []
```

won't work since you are comparing an array with another array.
Best way in Javascript for this is to check the length of the array.

```
aanimeArray.length === 0
```

means it is an empty array.

About the styling I think you need to show us the CSS code as well. I'm not sure what CardDeck component does...